# Entity Reference field fails when choosing from more than 1000 items

Tags: entities, nodes

I've set up my Drupal system to allow users to select from a list of locations, which are registered as nodes.

However, after importing my ~6000 locations the field lookup no longer works with the following error:

> PDOException: SELECT revision.vid AS vid, base.uid AS uid, revision.title AS title, revision.log AS log, 
>   revision.status AS status, revision.comment AS comment, revision.promote AS promote, revision.sticky AS sticky, 
>   base.nid AS nid, base.type AS type, base.language AS language, base.created AS created, base.changed AS changed, 
>   base.tnid AS tnid, base.translate AS translate, revision.timestamp AS revision_timestamp, 
>   revision.uid AS revision_uid 
>   FROM {node} base INNER JOIN {node_revision} revision ON revision.vid = base.vid 
>   WHERE (base.nid IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0, :db_condition_placeholder_1, :db_condition_placeholder_2, *... (trimmed) ...*
>    :db_condition_placeholder_5915, :db_condition_placeholder_5916)) 
>   ...
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1795 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)

I am using an Oracle backend, so it's possible this error is a quirk of Oracle. But in general, is the Entity Reference module intended to allow lookups on large lists of nodes? Or should I move to another module such as the References module?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested whether Oracle's performance with Entity Reference is substantively worse than another backend such as MySQL.

However, implementing the workaround [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842453/is-there-a-workaround-for-ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is) and converting a Drupal user.module query to a dynamic form to also implement partitioning worked, albeit with a 50 second execution time and a hugely increased PHP memory requirement. This is because of multiple complex queries across the whole node set.

Switching to use of the [references module](https://drupal.org/project/references) and the node_reference content type has vastly improved performance.